# SED delete repeated part of file

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have next configuration file:

```
[DEFAULT]
SenderCompID=BARXPB
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=4444
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=/apps/test
HttpAcceptPort=3333
TransportDataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX40.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.1=../../share/quickfix/FIX41.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.2=../../share/quickfix/FIX42.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.3=../../share/quickfix/FIX43.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.4=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX50.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP1=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP1.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP2=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP2.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
StartDay=sun
EndDay=sat

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=TUDOR-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=SECOR-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=ORTUS-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=CRABEL-TEST
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=FXCM-TEST
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=HIROSEIIJ-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=KNIGHT-TEST
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
```

My task is to change all [SESSION] tags by for example only one [SESSION] with CRABEL-TEST record, so the final configuration file should be look like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
SenderCompID=BARXPB
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=4444
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=/apps/test
HttpAcceptPort=3333
TransportDataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX40.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.1=../../share/quickfix/FIX41.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.2=../../share/quickfix/FIX42.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.3=../../share/quickfix/FIX43.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.4=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX50.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP1=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP1.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP2=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP2.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
StartDay=sun
EndDay=sat

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=CRABEL-TEST
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
```

Does it possible to make by SED? I used this expression

```
sed '/SESSION//CRABEL-TEST/,/SESSION/s/,SESSION,/,CRABEL-TEST,/g'
```

but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the  below GNU awk command,

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" file
[DEFAULT]
SenderCompID=BARXPB
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=4444
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=/apps/test
HttpAcceptPort=3333
TransportDataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX40.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.1=../../share/quickfix/FIX41.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.2=../../share/quickfix/FIX42.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.3=../../share/quickfix/FIX43.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.4=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX50.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP1=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP1.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP2=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP2.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
StartDay=sun
EndDay=sat

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=CRABEL-TEST
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good for me. Could you please explain how to save this change to file, I'm trying this variant: awk -v RS="\n\n" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" CRABEL-TEST.cfg < CRABEL-TEST.cfg

Comment: just do `awk -v RS="\n\n" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" infile > outfile`

Comment: output redirection operator is `>`

Comment: it works when infile and outfile have different names, but if I want to rewrite only one file (CRABEL-TEST.cfg for example) then this file is empty: `awk -v RS="\n\n" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" CRABEL-TEST.cfg > CRABEL-TEST.cfg`

Comment: then again transfer the datas from outfile to infile.

Comment: no, you can't do this, just redirect to another file. Like, `awk -v RS="\n\n" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" CRABEL-TEST.cfg > foo.cfg`

Comment: ok, it shouldn't be a problem, the main issue was solved by you. Thank you!

Comment: Then again reame the `foo.cfg` file to `CRABEL-TEST.cfg`. Before renaming, you have to delete the current one after creating foo.cfg

Comment: You should change `RS="\n\n"` to `RS=""` to make it more portable. Only `gnu awk` supports multiple characters in Record Selector

Comment: @Jotne you mean this `awk -v RS="" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{print} /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/{print}' ORS="\n\n" file`

Comment: Yes and you can put it behind the `code` when you have other variable there too. You do not need the `print` since its the default action of a test in `awk`, so you can do: `awk -v RS="" '/^\[DEFAULT\]/; /^\[SESSION\]/&&/CRABEL-TEST/' RS= ORS="\n\n" file`

Comment: Thanks @Jotne. Why a need for `RS=` at the last.

Comment: I did remove one more print in my post above.  You can have `-v RS=""` in front or `RS=""` behind or `RS=` behind.  You already have one variable behind `ORS="\n\n"` so no reason for variable all over.